# Per-chapter blank page disappears after Chapter 2

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, blank-page

I use LaTeX with the document class `book`. I´d like a blank page between chapters but it works only after Chapter 1. I've tried to force a blank page with `\newpage`, `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` and nothing happens.

How can I add a blank page? Why are they not included automatically after chapters?

Here is my `document.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{./estilos/estiloBase} 
\usepackage{./estilos/colores}  
\usepackage{./estilos/comandos}

\graphicspath{{./imagenes/}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\input{portada.tex}
\cleardoublepage

\input{primerahoja.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter 

\input{previo.tex}
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter 

\chapter{Introducción}
\label{cap:introduccion}
\input{cap1.tex}

\chapter{Descripción general del proyecto}
\label{cap:descripcion}
\input{cap2.tex}

\chapter{Contexto}
\label{cap:contexto}
\input{cap3.tex}
...

\appendix
\cleardoublepage
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage
\chapter{Manual de usuario}
\label{cap:manusuario}

\backmatter

\chapter*{Software utilizado}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Software utilizado}
\input{programas.tex}

\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía y referencias}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliografia}

\input{fdl-1.3.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Chapters in `book` start on a recto page (the page to the right when you open a book), so an empty page is only added if the previous chapter ended on a recto page, then the verso page between will be left blank.

Comment: An easy option here would be to use `\let\oldchapter\chapter \renewcommand{\chapter}{\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage\oldchapter}` so that the "empty page generation" is incorporated in your `\chapter` command. Note that this *should* give you an empty page, *always*.

Comment: So if I'm going to print this document (my thesis), What's the most recommended way? start chapters on a recto page always although a previous chapter finish on verso page? or left two blank pages between chapters in this case?

Comment: The standard approach would be either (1) start on recto, leaving a blank only if the previous chapter finished on recto or (2) start on new page without ever leaving a blank page after the previous chapter. I've never seen a book which skipped a page to put the new chapter on verso. Nor have I seen one which skipped two pages to get back to recto. (But there are many books I've not seen...) For a thesis, I would choose option (1) if you don't have guidelines to the contrary.

Comment: @JorgeAntequera: For this one would use the `openright` option of `book`. It's included by default, so you technically don't have to change a thing.

Comment: I don´t know if it's necessary to open a new thread for my question. My bibliography is not well indexed and it seems it's included into the previous chapter page in the index. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The `book` document class issues `openright` by default, which means that `\chapter` pages will start on a [recto (right) page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recto_and_verso) (typically an odd numbered page):

[image]

Therefore, it may be that some chapters end *without* a blank page while others end with one, depending on whether the subsequent page is recto or verso. If you wish to *always* have a blank page *before* a chapter, then you should pass the `openany` option to the document class and add the following to your preamble:

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter % Make a copy of \chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \clearpage% Clear the page and flush any pending floats
  \mbox{}% Put something on the new page
  \clearpage% Issue another \clearpage (perhaps not necessary, as \oldchapter may issue it)
  \oldchapter}% Regular chapter
```

The comments above describes the update to `\chapter`.

Most `book`s are set with `openright` with the chapters starting on recto in the `twoside` document option. Otherwise, if you're not printing your document in `twoside` mode, then `openany` would be a good option.